# How to use time picker dialog when the main class extends a fragment on its own?

Tags: android, android-fragments, dialog, timepicker

I can't understand how to use time picker dialog when my main class is a fragment on its own.

Please share some code so that I can solve this problem. I am stuck with this. Are there some additional methods that I would require to implement?

Using a separate TimePickerFragment class `public class FirstFragment extends Fragment implements TimePickerFragment.TimeDialogListener` throws the error: 
 Class 'FirstFragment' must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method 'onFinishDialog(String)' in 'TimeDialogListener'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Class 'FirstFragment' must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method 'onFinishDialog(String)' in 'TimeDialogListener'

This error indicate that you need to override the method `onFinishDialog(String` cause its declared as `abstract` in `TimeDialogListener`.
 Just override it in your class.

```
@Override
public void onFinishDialog(String s){

}
```

Apart from that you can directly use `TimePickerDialog` in your class as.

```
private void showTimePicker(){
    Calendar calendar =Calendar.getInstance();
    int hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int minute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    TimePickerDialog timePicker = new TimePickerDialog(context, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int selectedHour, int selectedMinute) {
            //Do the stuff here
        }
    }, hour, minute, false);
    timePicker.setTitle("Pick Time");
    timePicker.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a TimePickerDialog is pretty straightforward

```
int hour = currentTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
int minute = currentTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
TimePickerDialog timePicker;
timePicker = new TimePickerDialog(context, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int selectedHour, int selectedMinute) {
                //logic to handle time set event
            }
        }, hour, minute, true);//Yes 24 hour time
        timePicker.setTitle("Select Time");
        timePicker.show();
```